# Ajax loading element into page

Tags: ajax, load

Trying to load contents from an element into another element from another page, problem is in chrome it loads the entire page in to the element. See for yourself here: http://www.monsterhighshop.co.uk/gadgets-electonics

```
$(function(){

    e.preventDefault(); 
    /*  
    if uncomment the above line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
    if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link. 
    */

    //get the link location that was clicked
    $("a[rel='sort']").click(function(e){
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href')+"?rel=sort #categoryproducts-productlisting";
    $('#categoryproducts-productlisting').load(pageurl);

    //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
    if(pageurl!=window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
    }
    return false;  
});
});

/* the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without reload*/
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
$.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=sort',success: function(data){
    $('#categoryproducts-productlisting').html(data);
}});
});
```

Comment: I don't know what the problem is or what steps I'm supposed to take to reproduce it.

Comment: The problem is that instead of loading the contents of #categoryproducts-productlisting it loads the entire page but the problem is only in Chrome. go the url I posted in chrome and you'll see the problem

Comment: it's not doing it now, weird! the ajax simply doesn't work at all in IE or Google Chrome.